# What games have plan-moves-in-advance mechanics like Robo Rally?

Tags: recommendations, mechanics, robo-rally

I'm looking for games with pieces on a board that move and interact according to actions taken previously in the game. In Robo Rally you give your piece instructions in advance. I recall a similar game where you alter parts of the board before your piece reaches them. Any other games with similar mechanics to these would be welcome answers here.

Comment: Unfortunately, open-ended questions that request recommendations don't suit our Q&A format well (see the discussion [here](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/66/1678)) so I've voted to close your question. Try our chat-room or boardgamegeek.com for an active community that will definitely be able to help you with a recommendation. ([This thread may be of interest to you, perhaps](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/913630/games-where-you-programme-your-moves-a-few-turns-a))

Comment: Would Diplomacy meet the requirements?

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer no. multiple players planning at once is cool, but what I'm really looking for is each player queuing up multiple moves in advance.

Comment: Wings of War does this, a dogfighting game.

Answer (score 2):

[Space Alert](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/38453/space-alert) is a cooperative game in which you plan out your entire sequence of moves while trying to communicate with other players about the moves that you are making and the moves that they should make.  It uses very similar parts of your brain as RoboRally, with the exception that you're communicating about what each other are doing rather than trying to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Boardgamegeek has got a [list](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/68015/games-with-a-programming-mechanism/page/) on this topic.

I do however not know which game you are referring to.